# What is the relation between IO wait utilisation and load average

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-usage, load-average

Load average uses processes that are running or runnable or in uninterrupted sleep state. So do the processes in uninterrupted sleep state correspond with the `%wa` as per the `top` command? Both are referring to threads waiting for IO so it seems intuitive to assume that if one increases, the other will as well.

However, I'm seeing quite the opposite. %wait doesn't increase, the %idle is high and the load average is also high. I've read other questions on this but I have't found a satisfactory answer because they don't explain this behaviour.

- If the %wait does not include uninterrupted sleep state, then what is it exactly? Is it that the `%wait` does not really correspond with the load? (eg. the load could be 10 on a 2 CPU machine but it contributes to only 30% wait%)
- And how is this IO different from the IO referred to in uninterrupted state? What is a possible remedy in this case?

Clearly increasing CPU wouldn't help because there's tasks in the queue which the CPU is not picking up.